# Hourly Time Series Analysis on r in Hydrology

Tags: r

I am trying to separate the events from streamflow data. I have hourly data. I have run the code

```
dailyMQ <- data.frame(Date=seq(from=as.Date("01.01.2000", format="%d.%m.%Y"), 
to=as.Date("01.01.2004", format="%d.%m.%Y"), by="days"), 
discharge=rbeta(1462,2,20)*100)
```

for daily data. But I am trying for hourly data but getting errors.
Could anyone suggest me how to write a code for hourly data?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the code to reproduce the errors you get?

Comment: HourlyMQ <- data.frame(Date=seq(from=as.Date("01.01.2019", format="%d.%m.%Y"), to=as.Date("11.12.2019", format="%d.%m.%Y"),by="hours"),discharge=rbeta(8274,2,20))

Comment: This was the code which I was using.

Answer (score 0):

`Date` format can't directly be split into hours.

You could use `POSIXct` datetime format:

```r
HourlyMQ <- data.frame(Date=seq(from=as.POSIXct("01.01.2019", format="%d.%m.%Y"), to=as.POSIXct("11.12.2019", format="%d.%m.%Y"),by="hours"),discharge=rbeta(8257,2,20)) 
HourlyMQ
#>                     Date    discharge
#> 1    2019-01-01 00:00:00 0.2452214482
#> 2    2019-01-01 01:00:00 0.0620291334
#> 3    2019-01-01 02:00:00 0.0608788870
#> 4    2019-01-01 03:00:00 0.0697449808
#> 5    2019-01-01 04:00:00 0.0302780135
```

Comment: but There is a problem

Comment: Date Hours Discharge
20190101 0:00 0.1639
20190101 1:00 0.1639
20190101 2:00 0.1739
20190101 3:00 0.182
20190101 4:00 0.1887
20190101 5:00 0.1941
20190101 6:00 0.1991
20190101 7:00 0.2013
20190101 8:00 0.2015
20190101 9:00 0.1991
20190101 10:00 0.1947
20190101 11:00 0.1914
20190101 12:00 0.17
20190101 13:00 0.1839
 but in R

Comment: When we run this command then our HourlyMQ comes out to be

Comment: for discharge, 0:00 - 0.0666, 1:00 - 0.1266, 2:00 - 0.1179, 3:00 - 0.1624

Comment: Could you edit your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/13513328)?

Comment: Hi, I solved this problem. Thank you so much for the guidance. I will reach out to you whenever I got stuck.

Comment: Hi, Could you please help me to find "Run_WebFlood()" command?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://rdrr.io/github/PhilippBuehler/FloodR/man/Run_WebFlood.html

Comment: Yes yes, but could not able to run RunFlood command